# Java: Converting String to and from ByteBuffer and associated problems

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, nio, bytebuffer

I am using Java NIO for my socket connections, and my protocol is text based, so I need to be able to convert Strings to ByteBuffers before writing them to the SocketChannel, and convert the incoming ByteBuffers back to Strings.  Currently, I am using this code:

```
public static Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
public static CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
public static CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

public static ByteBuffer str_to_bb(String msg){
  try{
    return encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(msg));
  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  return null;
}

public static String bb_to_str(ByteBuffer buffer){
  String data = "";
  try{
    int old_position = buffer.position();
    data = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
    // reset buffer's position to its original so it is not altered:
    buffer.position(old_position);  
  }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
  return data;
}
```

This works most of the time, but I question if this is the preferred (or simplest) way to do each direction of this conversion, or if there is another way to try.  Occasionally, and seemingly at random, calls to `encode()` and `decode()` will throw a 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = FLUSHED, new state = CODING_END` exception, or similar, even if I am using a new ByteBuffer object each time a conversion is done.  Do I need to synchronize these methods?  Any better way to convert between Strings and ByteBuffers?  Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check out the [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) API descriptions - You should follow a **specific sequence of method calls** to avoid this problem.  For example, for `CharsetEncoder`:

1. Reset the encoder via the `reset` method, unless it has not been used before;
2. Invoke the `encode` method zero or more times, as long as additional input may be available, passing `false` for the endOfInput argument and filling the input buffer and flushing the output buffer between invocations;
3. Invoke the `encode` method one final time, passing `true` for the endOfInput argument; and then
4. Invoke the `flush` method so that the encoder can flush any internal state to the output buffer.

By the way, this is the same approach I am using for NIO although some of my colleagues are converting each char directly to a byte in the knowledge they are only using ASCII, which I can imagine is probably faster.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was very helpful!  I discovered that I did have multiple threads calling my conversion functions concurrently, even though I had not designed it to allow that.  I fixed it by calling charset.newEncoder().encode() and charset.newDecoder().decode() to ensure I was using a new encoder/decoder each time to avoid concurrency issues, or needlessly having to synchronize on those objects, which don't share meaningful data in my case.  I also ran some tests and found no measurable performance difference in using newEncoder()/newDecoder() each time!

Comment: No problem.  You could avoid having to create new encoders / decoders each time but still remain thread safe by using ThreadLocal, and lazily creating a dedicated encoder / decoder per thread as needed (this is what I've done).

Comment: Could this work?  new String(bb.array(), 0,bb.array().length, "UTF-8")

Answer (score 51):

Unless things have changed, you're better off with

```
public static ByteBuffer str_to_bb(String msg, Charset charset){
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes(charset));
}

public static String bb_to_str(ByteBuffer buffer, Charset charset){
    byte[] bytes;
    if(buffer.hasArray()) {
        bytes = buffer.array();
    } else {
        bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
    }
    return new String(bytes, charset);
}
```

Usually buffer.hasArray() will be either always true or always false depending on your use case. In practice, unless you really want it to work under any circumstances, it's safe to optimize away the branch you don't need.

Answer (score 14):

Answer by Adamski is a good one and describes the steps in an encoding operation when using the general encode method (that takes a byte buffer as one of the inputs)

However, the method in question (in this discussion) is a variant of encode - **encode(CharBuffer in)**. This is a **convenience method that implements the entire encoding operation**. (Please see java docs reference in P.S.)

As per the docs, **This method should therefore not be invoked if an encoding operation is already in progress** (which is what is happening in ZenBlender's code -- using static encoder/decoder in a multi threaded environment).

Personally, I like to use *convenience* methods (over the more general encode/decode methods) as they take away the burden by performing all the steps under the covers.

ZenBlender and Adamski have already suggested multiple ways options to safely do this in their comments. Listing them all here:

- Create a new encoder/decoder object when needed for each operation (not efficient as it could lead to a large number of objects). OR,
- Use a ThreadLocal to avoid creating new encoder/decoder for each operation. OR,
- Synchronize the entire encoding/decoding operation (this might not be preferred unless sacrificing some concurrency is ok for your program)

P.S.

java docs references:

1. Encode (convenience) method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29
2. General encode method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20boolean%29