# How to convert amqp message sent as Buffer.from to Java String

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, amqp

I have 2 services communicating via AMQP. One uses Javascript with amqplib to send a messageObject `{"message":"Success"}` like this:

```
channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(messageObject)));
```

The Java Service consumes the message using spring rabbit like this:

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_NAME)
  public void receiveMessageQueue(String message) {
```

the content of that message is string representing an array of bytes. I tried to convert it using the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array) It works for 95% of the message But my result still contains some unintelligble characters. Seems like it cannot translate the `{` and `}`

```
\u0017 "message":"Success" \f
```

So I am wondering, should I change something on the sender side or the receiver side. I'd much rather change the sender side since I have a lot of Java services that expect a ready to use JSON String to be parsed into objects and I don't want to have to update all of them and convert the messages.

**EDIT**
[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354891/java-bytebuffer-to-string) as mentioned by SMA did not help. Resulting String is exactly the same as the input:

```
"123,34,106,111,98,73,100,34,58,34,52,54,99,51,101,100,53,54,45,49,101,52,99,45,52,101,49,101,45,97,56,55,55,45,50,55,100,54,53,102,56,50,55,48,51,48,34,44,34,109,101,115,115,97,103,101,34,58,34,83,117,99,99,101,115,115,102,117,108,108,121,32,115,117,98,109,105,116,116,101,100,32,116,111,32,112,46,118,100,115,105,116,116,64,100,105,97,108,111,103,119,111,114,107,115,46,100,101,34,125"
```

All I can do right now is:

```
private String convert(String byteString) {
    String[] byteValues = byteString.substring(1, byteString.length() - 1).split(",");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteValues.length];
    for (int i=0, len=bytes.length; i<len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(byteValues[i].trim());
    }
    return new String(bytes).replace('\u0017','{').replace('\f','}');
  }
```

but that seems too hackish. It feels like there should be an easy solition to communicte a JSON string between javascript and java using amqp.

**SOLUTION**

I found a way to send the message in a way that spring rabbit will understand:

```
channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(messageObject),'utf8'), {contentType:'text/plain', contentEncoding: 'UTF-8'});
```

Appearently the properties contentType and contentEncoding are a convention, used by the Spring Rabbit message consumer. Now the Java service gets the correct JSON string.

Comment: can you please try the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354891/java-bytebuffer-to-string  to convert your byte buffer into a String (The default Buffer.from encoding is UTF-8)  Please update and see if that worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Didn't help though. I added the String I receive on the Java End

Comment: Great that you resolved it.