# Java NIO - SocketChannel.write() on server many times but Client only receive result once

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking, socketchannel

I'm doing an exercise requires making a **server - client chat program** using `Java Non-Blocking IO`. At the moment, the way the program works is simple: when a client send a message to the server, the server (which already keep track of all the clients) *echo* the message back to all the clients.

This is my some parts of my server-side code:

```
public static ByteBuffer str_to_bb(String msg) {
    try {
        return encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(msg));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static void broadcastMessage(String nickname, String message) {
    System.out.println(">clientSocketChannels size " + clientSocketChannels.size());
    Iterator clientSocketChannelsIterator = clientSocketChannels.iterator();
    while (clientSocketChannelsIterator.hasNext()) {
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) clientSocketChannelsIterator.next();
        try {
            ByteBuffer bb = str_to_bb(message);
            System.out.println("bufferRemaining: " + bb.remaining()); // returns 2048
            int writeResult = sc.write(bb);
            System.out.println("writeResult: " + writeResult); // returns 2048
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my client-side code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by ThaiSon on 7/6/2015.
 */
public class ChatRoomClientGUI {
    private JTextArea textAreaMessages;
    private JTextField textFieldMessage;
    private JButton buttonSendMsg;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JLabel txtFieldInfo;

    private static InetAddress inetAddress;
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static Scanner input = null;
    private static PrintWriter output = null;

    private static ChatRoomClientGUI singleton;

    public ChatRoomClientGUI() {
        singleton = this;
        buttonSendMsg.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    String message = textFieldMessage.getText();
                    output.println(message);
                    textFieldMessage.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame promptFrame = new JFrame();
        Object nickname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(promptFrame, "Enter your nickname:");
        promptFrame.dispose();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChatRoomClientGUI");
        frame.setContentPane(new ChatRoomClientGUI().jPanel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("> Client with nickname " + nickname);

        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        accessServer(nickname.toString());
    }

    private static void accessServer(String nickname) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(inetAddress, PORT);
            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            output.println(nickname); // Register nickname with the server

            //TODO update the txtFieldInfo content

            // Create a new thread to listen to InputStream event
            InputStreamEvent inputStreamEvent = new InputStreamEvent(socket);
            inputStreamEvent.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void handleInputStream(){
        String response = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("TODO " + response);
        singleton.textAreaMessages.append(response + "\n");
    }

    static class InputStreamEvent extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        public InputStreamEvent(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int read;
                while (true){
                    if(inputStream.available() > 0){
                        handleInputStream();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing with now is that when I use a client (which works well with the old `multithreaded server`) to send message to the server, the client only get return the *first* message it sends. All the next responses from the server is empty (the server does send back, but only an empty message).

So my attempts to debug includes:

- check if the messages from the client has reach the server or not. They does.
- log the `buffer.remaining()` and `socketChannel.write(buffer)` result as shown above, all the log result seems to be *normal* to me.

Hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: are you sure you are reading correctly on the client?

Comment: The same client works well with the old multithreaded server, and the client can display exactly the first response from the server :/

Comment: What is `encoder` and `clientSocketChannels`?

Comment: `encoder` is here: from `public static Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
public static CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
public static CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();` (I copy it from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252468/java-converting-string-to-and-from-bytebuffer-and-associated-problems) and clientSocketChannels is an ArrayList of all SocketChannels (each SocketChannel is of one client that is connecting to the server)

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty message in TCP. The code you've posted indicates that 2048 bytes were written. *Ergo* the problem is in the client. Post the code.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I've just udated my client-side code. Please have a look :)

Comment: Have you tried flushing the message after each write? `sc.write(bb); sc.flush();`

Comment: @Zymus there's no method flush for a SocketChannel object

Comment: I believe it's because the scanner is looking for the `nextLine` but the message you're sending does not have a line separator at the end. Try doing `CharBuffer.wrap(msg + "\r\n")` in your `str_to_bb` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This:

   ```
   if(inputStream.available() > 0){
   ```

   Get rid of this test. With it, your client is smoking the CPU. Without it, it will block in `readLine()` as God intended.
2. Are you sure your server is still sending lines? with line terminators? If it isn't, `readLine()` will block forever looking for one, until end of stream or an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I referred the code explain by EJP on this link [Java NIO Server/Client Chat App - sending data only by closing the socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192279/java-nio-server-client-chat-app-sending-data-only-by-closing-the-socket)

it solves my problem. use this code

```
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(200);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT|SelectionKey.OP_READ|SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            boolean isConnected = socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5000));
            if(isConnected) {
                System.out.println("Connected, de-registering OP_CONNECT");
            }
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                private SocketChannel socketChannel;
                private Selector selector;
                public Runnable init(SocketChannel socketChannel, Selector selector) {
                    this.socketChannel = socketChannel;
                    this.selector = selector;
                    return this;
                }
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(200);
                        while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                            int keys = selector.select();
                            if(keys > 0) { 
                                for(SelectionKey key : selector.selectedKeys()) {
                                    if(key.isConnectable()) {
                                        boolean finishConnectResult = socketChannel.finishConnect();
                                        socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                                        System.out.println("Finished Connect : " + finishConnectResult);
                                    }
                                    if(key.isReadable()) {
                                        int bytesRead = 0;
                                        while((bytesRead = socketChannel.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                            buf.flip();
                                            while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
                                                System.out.print((char)buf.get());
                                            }
                                            buf.clear();
                                        }
                                        if(bytesRead == -1) {
                                            key.channel().close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.init(socketChannel, selector)).start();

            while(true) {
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    buf.clear();
                    buf.put(scanner.nextLine().getBytes());
                    buf.flip();
                    socketChannel.write(buf);
                    buf.flip();
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have done the mistake setting this flag
`key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
)`
instead of below.
use this 
`socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);`