# Go from ByteBuffer to String directly but with no intermediary byte[]?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Is there an approach that avoids having to copy byte[] from ByteBuffer with the ByteBuffer.get() operation.

I was looking at this post [Java: Converting String to and from ByteBuffer and associated problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252468/java-converting-string-to-and-from-bytebuffer-and-associated-problems)

and that causes an intermediary CharBuffer which I don't want as well.

I would like it to go from ByteBuffer to String.

When I know I have a byte[] underlying, this is easy with the code like so

```
new String(data, offset, length, charSet);
```

I was hoping for something similar with ByteBuffer.  I am beginning to think this may not be possible?  I need to decode N bytes of my ByteBuffer really.

This may be a bit of premature optimization but I am really just curious and wanted to test out the performance and squeeze every little bit out.  (personal project really).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Do you mean [ByteBuffer.array()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29) ?

Answer (score 2):

Not really for a direct `ByteBuffer`, no. You need to have intermediate something, because `String` doesn't take a `ByteBuffer` as a constructor argument, and you can't wrap one (or even a `char[]`). If the buffer is non-direct, you can use the `array()` method to get a reference to the backing array (which isn't an intermediate array) and create a `String` out of that.

On the plus side, there's probably a lot more performance sensitive places in your project.

Comment: well, I am playing with an nio library and testing shows the byte copying to be expensive :( so I was hoping to prevent more large byte array copies and go direct.  It really seems like they should have this feature...shucks.

Comment: but yes, in the context of a full application stack, it would be minimal

Comment: I can imagine there can be some issues trying to create a Java `String` from basically unmanaged (as far as Java is concerned) memory without having any copying of bytes between.